# Show the user that iCloud sync is in progress

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I currently have my CoreData-iCloud setup working. Every time the user adds/deletes/edits entires in one of his devices, the changes are synced to iCloud (if available) and then pushed to his other devices when he opens the app.

Unfortunately, iCloud is not instantaneous. When the user opens the app in his second device, it takes 10~20 seconds on a solid connection for the synced data to appear.

Is there any way to detect when the application connects with iCloud, to inform the user that there's actually something going on, and the app is working (show a little spinner somewhere)?

At least to be able to manually trigger an iCloud update via pull to refresh, or something. It would be awesome being able to show the user something that tells him "your data is on your way, hold a little longer".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these sample apps, they use the status of log files in iCloud to determine when upload or download activity is underway.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: It should be 100% reliable because it's directly monitoring the sync engines activities, even though I only implemented it as a bit of a novelty. You can even reliably track from a save to uploading the resulting transaction log file or from detecting a file that has not been downloaded to the point an import notification is received.

Comment: There's probably a delay after downloading completes but before the "did import" notification happens, while the data is actually imported. Is that right?

Comment: I have not spent much time checking delays because Apples iCloud seems to have a mind of its own when it comes to timing of synchronisation.  The gaps I have been unable to cover are across devices.  For example when the app executes a MOC save (and if there were changes) you know that there must be a transaction log created and that it must be uploaded to iCloud - so you can display something to indicate to the user a sync transaction has been started and when it has been completed.  What you can't do is know this is happening from another device.

Comment: The only way to tell if the 'world' of your app is in sync is to check that each device's iCloud files have been properly synchronised.  A given device can't ever be certain that another device does not have uploads pending on its own.

Comment: I'll accept your answer for the moment as the most accurate solution for this problem. Its not the optimal and it feels hackish, but its the best. Thank you.

Comment: @TomHarrington there is a delay depending on the size of the data in the log. Importing the baseline especially takes quiet a while. On some occasions the import never starts, even though all of the transaction logs downloaded successfully. I discovered this after deleting and reinstalling the app a couple of times. Any of you experienced this before?

Comment: *correction - after turning on the ubiquity log Level 3, I noticed the import did start, but appears to be stuck in replaceGlobalObjectID:withGlobalObjectID:

Answer (score 1):

There's no documented API for checking the status of transaction logs with CoreData-iCloud. There's definitely no way to "trigger" an iCloud update, but to check pending data, you might be able to hack together something using NSMetadataQuery and iCloud KVS, but it's also going to be imprecise and unpredictable. Hopefully this is added in iOS8 (you might want to file a Radar while you're at it).